# DI with using base class (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have base Attachment controller
Here is code of it

```
    public class ApiAttachmentControllerBase<T> : PM101MobileApiController where T : Entity<int>
    {
        private readonly IObjectStorageManager _storageManager;
        private readonly IRepository<T> _repository;

        public ApiAttachmentControllerBase(IObjectStorageManager storageManager, IRepository<T> repository)
        {
            _storageManager = storageManager;
            _repository = repository;
        }



         private void CheckFileSize(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file.Length > PM101Consts.MaxAttachmentSize)
            {
                throw new UserFriendlyException(L("Attachment_Warn_SizeLimit", PM101Consts.MaxAttachmentSizeMb.ToString()));
            }

        }

        private void CheckFileType(IFormFile file, params string[] supportedTypes)
        {
            if (supportedTypes.Any())
            {
                var extention = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                if (!supportedTypes.ToList().Contains(extention))
                {
                    throw new UserFriendlyException(L("Attachment_Warn_Type", extention));
                }
            }

        }
   }
}
```

I inherited it in another controller like this

```
 public class InspectionsController : ApiAttachmentControllerBase<Inspection>
{
    private readonly IRepository<Inspection> _inspectionRepository;

    public InspectionsController(IObjectStorageManager storageManager, IRepository<Inspection> repository,
        IRepository<Inspection> inspectionRepository) : base(storageManager, repository)
    {
        _inspectionRepository = inspectionRepository;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Method for posting pre-inspection
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>When you start pre inspection you send just jobId, tenantId, and status
    /// When you finishing inspection you send full DTO with all fields</remarks>
    /// <response code="200">Returns if pre inspection created
    /// </response>
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddPreInspection(CreatePreInspectionDto input)
    {
        var preInspection = new Inspection();
        ObjectMapper.Map(input, preInspection);
        await _inspectionRepository.InsertAsync(preInspection);
        return Ok();
    }
```

In `AddPreInspection` I tried to use repository like `repository.InsertAsync`

But it not works, so I make DI for repository like `private read-only IRepository<Inspection> _inspectionRepository;`

Is this a good practice or I can use the repository from the base class?

If yes, how I can do it?

Comment: Inject it into your base constructor, as you have already done for `storageManager` and `repository`. Is it going to be used in multiple places? If not then it doesn't need to be in the base class.

Comment: It seems you don't have issue, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is for code reviews :)

Comment: Okay, but I need to call this repo in another controller, where I inherit Base Controller, so how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the base `ApiAttachmentControllerBase` have a `protected`, rather than `private`, repository then the `InspectionsController` will be able to access it.

The `protected` access modifier allows the member to be accessed by the current class, or a derived class.

```
public class ApiAttachmentControllerBase<T> : PM101MobileApiController where T : Entity<int>
{
  private readonly IObjectStorageManager _storageManager;
  protected readonly IRepository<T> Repository;

  public ApiAttachmentControllerBase(IObjectStorageManager storageManager, IRepository<T> repository)
  {
    _storageManager = storageManager;
    Repository = repository;
  }
....
```